# How to move a node in XML using XSLT mapping with condition

Tags: xml, xslt

I've got an xml similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<MATMAS05>
    <IDOC BEGIN="1">
        <EDI_DC40 SEGMENT="1">
            <CREDAT>20180822</CREDAT>
            <CRETIM>180201</CRETIM>
            <SERIAL>20180821134354</SERIAL>
        </EDI_DC40>
        <E1MARAM SEGMENT="1">
            <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
            <MATNR>000000000002000010</MATNR>
            <E1MARA1 SEGMENT="1">
                <MAXC>0.000</MAXC>
                <MAXC_TOL>0.0</MAXC_TOL>
            </E1MARA1>
            <E1MAKTM SEGMENT="1">
                <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                <SPRAS>E</SPRAS>
            </E1MAKTM>
            <E1MARCM SEGMENT="1">
                <MSGFN>009</MSGFN>
                <WERKS>3030</WERKS>
                <E1MARDM SEGMENT="1">
                    <MSGFN>009</MSGFN>
                    <LGORT>1000</LGORT>
                </E1MARDM>
                <E1MPGDM SEGMENT="1">
                    <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                </E1MPGDM>
            </E1MARCM>
            <E1MARCM SEGMENT="1">
                <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                <WERKS>3040</WERKS>
                <E1MARDM SEGMENT="1">
                    <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                    <LGORT>1000</LGORT>
                </E1MARDM>
                <E1MPGDM SEGMENT="1">
                    <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                </E1MPGDM>
            </E1MARCM>
            <E1MARMM SEGMENT="1">
                <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                <MEINH>EA</MEINH>
            </E1MARMM>
            <E1MBEWM SEGMENT="1">
                <MSGFN>009</MSGFN>
                <BWKEY>3030</BWKEY>
            </E1MBEWM>
            <E1MBEWM SEGMENT="1">
                <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                <BWKEY>3040</BWKEY>
            </E1MBEWM>
            <E1MLANM SEGMENT="1">
                <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                <ALAND>AU</ALAND>
            </E1MLANM>
        </E1MARAM>
    </IDOC>
</MATMAS05>
```

I need to move E1MBEWM nodes into appropriate E1MARCM node where BWKEY=WERKS

So, basically it should be the output like that:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<MATMAS05>
    <IDOC BEGIN="1">
        <EDI_DC40 SEGMENT="1">
            <CREDAT>20180822</CREDAT>
            <CRETIM>180201</CRETIM>
            <SERIAL>20180821134354</SERIAL>
        </EDI_DC40>
        <E1MARAM SEGMENT="1">
            <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
            <MATNR>000000000002000010</MATNR>
            <E1MARA1 SEGMENT="1">
                <MAXC>0.000</MAXC>
                <MAXC_TOL>0.0</MAXC_TOL>
            </E1MARA1>
            <E1MAKTM SEGMENT="1">
                <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                <SPRAS>E</SPRAS>
            </E1MAKTM>
            <E1MARCM SEGMENT="1">
                <MSGFN>009</MSGFN>
                <WERKS>3030</WERKS>
                <E1MARDM SEGMENT="1">
                    <MSGFN>009</MSGFN>
                    <LGORT>1000</LGORT>
                </E1MARDM>
                <E1MPGDM SEGMENT="1">
                    <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                </E1MPGDM>
                <E1MBEWM SEGMENT="1">
                   <MSGFN>009</MSGFN>
                   <BWKEY>3030</BWKEY>
                </E1MBEWM>
            </E1MARCM>
            <E1MARCM SEGMENT="1">
                <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                <WERKS>3040</WERKS>
                <E1MARDM SEGMENT="1">
                    <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                    <LGORT>1000</LGORT>
                </E1MARDM>
                <E1MPGDM SEGMENT="1">
                    <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                </E1MPGDM>
                <E1MBEWM SEGMENT="1">
                   <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                   <BWKEY>3040</BWKEY>
                </E1MBEWM>
            </E1MARCM>
            <E1MARMM SEGMENT="1">
                <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                <MEINH>EA</MEINH>
            </E1MARMM>
            <E1MLANM SEGMENT="1">
                <MSGFN>005</MSGFN>
                <ALAND>AU</ALAND>
            </E1MLANM>
        </E1MARAM>
    </IDOC>
</MATMAS05>
```

the possible issue is that sometimes E1MBEWM node might not be in incoming message.

I'm trying to use XSLT something like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="E1MARCM/*[1]">
  <xsl:copy-of select="/*/E1MBEWM[1]"/>
  <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="/*/E1MBEWM[1]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but it doesn't give result needed if there are several E1MARCM nodes. I understand that I need to use two for each cycles, but not sure how to implement it here.

Can you please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Little Santi.
I've managed to play and find a solution which suits my purpose:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="E1MARCM">
  <E1MARCM>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" mode="just-copy"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="just-copy"/>
    <xsl:variable name="mywerks" select="WERKS"></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:copy-of select="../E1MBEWM[BWKEY=$mywerks]"/>
  </E1MARCM>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*|@*" mode="just-copy">
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I've got some duplication, because now I have E1MBEWM in E1MARCM and out of it, but I can filter it out later.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is an XSL with two levels (two templates):

1. The first, for the root node, will browse every `E1MARCM` node and build up a node equal to the matched.
2. The Second, for each `E1MARCM` node, will copy a node `E1MBEWM` that meet the required criteria.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
   <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

   <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

   <xsl:template match="/XML">
   <XML>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="E1MARCM"/>
   </XML>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="E1MARCM">
     <E1MARCM SEGMENT="{@SEGMENT}">
       <MSGFN><xsl:value-of select="MSGFN"/></MSGFN>
       <WERKS><xsl:value-of select="WERKS"/></WERKS>
       <xsl:variable name="mywerks" select="WERKS"></xsl:variable>
       <xsl:copy-of select="../E1MBEWM[BWKEY=$mywerks]"/>
     </E1MARCM>
   </xsl:template>

   </xsl:stylesheet>
   ```

(Note that it is necessary to store in a temporary variable the value of a certain node before putting it into an xpath expression whose context node is different.)

## Update

And, for generalizing the attributes and subnodes, a third target is needed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/XML">
<XML>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="E1MARCM"/>
</XML>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="E1MARCM">
  <E1MARCM>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" mode="just-copy"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="just-copy"/>
    <xsl:variable name="mywerks" select="WERKS"></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:copy-of select="../E1MBEWM[BWKEY=$mywerks]"/>
  </E1MARCM>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*|@*" mode="just-copy">
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I can't really list all fields from E1MARCM segments, as it's really be usually and it might have/not have some fields depending on the logic. So, I definitely need to copy whole node without listing fields in it. I actually have other nodes than E1MARCM in the root node. I've just tried to simplify the example to make it easier to understand.

Comment: It looks like I've over simplified the input and that's why the solution still require adaptation. I have the following (still simplified) input. This time I've listed all nodes I have with a couple of fields in each. The aim is to get all nodes, but put E1MBEWM nodes into appropriate E1MARCM node where BWKEY=WERKS. I actually can have E1MBEWM where they are, but have an appropriate copy in E1MARCM. I will add it in a couple of minutes as a separate response

Comment: I've just updated the question with a full structure... Now it has all nodes and I've left just a couple of field in each of them.